# Firebase Deployment Error "Error: Functions did not deploy properly."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, continuous-deployment, webdeploy

I have deployed Firebase functions in the past many times. For some reasons, recently (around 2-3 days) I am frequently getting error while deployment. I am using windows to release the code. When I tried with setting up the same project in my Linux system and Mac system the deployment works correctly. What may be the issue for the release from Windows environment.

**The following is the issues getting while deployment.**

!  functions[payment(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
admin
cancellation
cost
createStripeCharge
customer
driver
driverLiveTracking
generalSettings
notification
order
payment

To try redeploying those functions, run:
firebase deploy --only "functions:admin,functions:cancellation,functions:cost,functions:createStripeCharge,functions:customer,functions:driver,functions:driverLiveTracking,functions:generalSettings,functions:notification,functions:order,functions:payment"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

**Following is the deployment command I am using for**

"echo Deploying Functions && npm run lint &&  npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions"

Please share your knowledge over the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. On building, I found that the node modules and lib functions are not replacing correctly with the new build. I have done a name changing previously and that are not reflecting in the new build.

Steps followed:

- Removed node modules and lib files
- Npm install
- Npm run serve

And a new build is worked fine as well. I got the same issue using Jenkins build also. I just manually removed the same in server also.

Answer (score 2):

**You can find the issue by examining the actual logs. view them using this command**

```
firebase functions:log
```

The specific issue will be visible there. I sometimes had error as simple as a missing packages in package.json

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I searched for "error" in the log, and it turns out there was something wrong with my `package-lock.json`. I deleted it and did `npm install` and that fixed the problem.